# Is there a way to update the lightbox album/gallery when using it with a filter?

Tags: javascript, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm using Isotope & Lightbox2 to create a filterable gallery, which is working fine. However, when I open the light box while browsing a specific filtered gallery, navigating through the lightbox also displays other images.

Is it possible to change the list of images displayed by the lightbox based on the filter?

I'm using vanilla javascript.

I tried updating the lightbox album, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think I have seen somewhere demo where Fancybox is combined with filterable gallery, so, maybe save time and choose Fancybox.